# How to know how long did it take to copy files in Windows?

Tags: windows, copy

I need to copy 1TB in files by Windows O/S.

After all files were copied, is there any way to know how much time did it take to copy all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying 1TB of files, I suggest you use something like [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29).  It will summarize the time taken for the copy (as well as providing a host of other benefits that are particularly important when copying large and/or many files).

Answer (score 1):

Print date and time beforehand and afterwards?

Or use something like [timethis](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3087).